# material-ui TextField disable Browser autoComplete

Tags: html, forms, input, autocomplete, material-ui

I use material ui v0.20.0 and I have to prohibit saving the password for a user with TextField. I added props to TextField autocomplete='nope' cause not all the browsers understand autocomplete='off'. It seems that the last version of Chrome 63 does not accept it. Sometimes it does not work and sometimes it does. I can not get why it works so hectic. When chrome asks to save password and I save it, and after that I want to edit input I still have this : [image]

```
  <TextField
         name='userName'
         floatingLabelText={<FormattedMessage id='users.username' />}
         value={name || ''}
         onChange={(e, name) => this.changeUser({name})}
         // autoComplete='new-password'

    /> 

    <TextField
        name='password'
        floatingLabelText={<FormattedMessage id='users.passwords.new' />}
        type='password'
        value={password || ''}
        onChange={(e, password) => this.changeUser({password})}
        autoComplete='new-password'
   />
```

Looks like it works in Firefox(v57.0.4)

By default TextField does not have autoComplete='off'
[image]

Comment: Adding `autoComplete="new-password"` as a prop to `<TextField>` is what works currently as of this comment

Comment: This case is explained and covered by the documentation and it worked like a charm for me
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete-autofill
TL;DR
<TextField
     inputProps={{
          autoComplete: 'new-password'
     }} />

Comment: As for the newest MUI this answer is the only one that works as intended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72994887/9973445

Answer (score 70):

To Disable auto Complete in material-ui TextField.
its works for me

```
<TextField
  name='password'
  autoComplete='off'
  type='text'
  ... 
/>
```

should be autoComplete='off'

```
autoComplete='off'
```

Comment: Confirmation: this works in Material UI (@material-ui/core: ^4.11.2). Tested on 5th Jan 2020.

Comment: How do you turn off autocomplete for a password field?

Comment: This does not work in MUI anymore. The different answer (inputProps autoComplete: 'new-password') works as intended.

Answer (score 68):

This seems to have worked for me (we are using material ui with redux form)

```
 <Textfield
  inputProps={{
    autocomplete: 'new-password',
    form: {
      autocomplete: 'off',
    },
  }}
  />
```

"new-password" works if the input is type="password
"off" works if its a regular text field wrapped in a form

Comment: This was driving me nuts! Thank you.

Comment: Same! How insane! Thanks again.

Comment: this doesn't work anymore Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (x86_64) OSX

Comment: Works on Chrome 97. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect! This spectacular answer did the job on Chrome 102. Putting `autocomplete` inside `inputProps` is important...

Comment: It's "InputProps", not "inputProps", those are two different props, and if you use typescript, "inputProps" won't allow a key named "autocomplete". Anyway `InputProps={{autoComplete: "off"}}` worked for me

Answer (score 24):

With Material UI input you can use

> autoComplete="new-password"

So you will have something like this input :

```
<TextField
 autoComplete="new-password"
/>
```

This was a big help for example to avoid more styles from the browser on a login page.

Hope this helps to others!

Comment: Yes thanks! With Material UI I just tested it, even with `<TextField type="password" />`, adding `autoComplete="new-password"` will also disable autocomplete on Email TextField.

Answer (score 17):

the autocomplete must be inside inputProps

```
<TextField
   inputProps={{
      autoComplete: 'off'
   }}
/>
```

is good way

Comment: adding autoComplete: 'off' to input does not disable autocomplete

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Comment: This caused issues of missing params, I think to include ...params.inputProps, might be what fixed it for me, as shown in the linked answer, if other people have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737792/3810321

Comment: if you have others inputProps, yes ! you shoulds dump this ! like :  inputProps={{
      ...yourInputProps /* or your naming */
      autoComplete: 'off'
   }}

Comment: This worked for me on some field types like name but not for contact fields like email, phone and address. `autoComplete: 'none'` worked for me on those.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in the Material-UI [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete-autofill):
Add the following to the TextField.

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{
     ...params.inputProps,
     autoComplete: 'new-password',
   }}
 />
```

It disables the browser autofill suggestions and can also be used on the Autocomplete's TextField component.
***Note**:  Also there are two separate properties inputProps and InputProps. You can apply both on the same item. However, the inputProps prop fixes the autocomplete issues.*

Answer (score 9):

Try enclose the Textfield inside the form tag with noValidate prop.
Eg:

```
<form noValidate>
            <TextField
                label={'Enter Name'}
                required
                fullWidth
                autoFocus={true}
                value={text}
                onChange={(e) => (text = e.target.value)}
            />
</form>
```

I don't know for what reason the autoComplete prop doesn't work. But the above works.

Comment: Using other alternatives also mess the behavior of the [Autocomplete element](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) This solution worked for me without affecting the Autocomplete behavior. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only way to stop chrome from autofilling a TextField inside a Material-UI Autocomplete field. None of the other answers work.

Comment: chrome still give you a suggestion list even you set the `autoComplete` to off in Material UI, I tried other values like 'none', it worked for some inputs, but broke others. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 8):

The key is to use a random text that the browser has not saved previously from any form the user has filled such as "&#6#+" or "ViewCrunch". This will also solve auto complete issue with chrome browser that leaves all fields in blue background.

```
<TextField
     autoComplete='ViewCrunch'
/>
```

//Recent versions of MUI

```
<TextField
     autoComplete='off'
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Fixed. Just need to add above real input field

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion - MDN
https://medium.com/paul-jaworski/turning-off-autocomplete-in-chrome-ee3ff8ef0908 - medium
                                        tested on EDGE, Chrome(latest v63), Firefox Quantum (57.0.4 64-бит), Firefox(52.2.0)
                                        fake fields are a workaround for chrome/opera autofill getting the wrong fields

```
 const fakeInputStyle = {opacity: 0, float: 'left', border: 'none', height: '0', width: '0'}

 <input type="password" name='fake-password' autoComplete='new-password' tabIndex='-1' style={fakeInputSyle} />

  <TextField
  name='userName'
  autoComplete='nope'
  ... 
/>

<TextField
      name='password'
      autoComplete='new-password'
      ... 
    />
```

Comment: this worked for me. It's hard to believe this is the only way to disable autocomplete.

Answer (score 5):

The `autoComplete` attribute of the input props and text field props are meant to follow the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill).

It seems to not work for some of us. Strangely, I don't see `off` listed in the spec but it **doesn't** turn it off for me while strings such as `nope`, `nahhhh` do - that is strings that aren't in the spec.

So I settled with `none` which seems to turn off the suggestions and keep things neat.

Also, setting the `autoComplete` prop of the text field didn't work for me...

```
<TextField
    className={classes.textfield}
    label='Invitees'
    placeholder='A comma seperated list of emails'
    variant='outlined'
    value={users}
    onChange={onChange}
    inputProps={{
        autoComplete: 'none',
    }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

Whenever you want to disable a autofill for the password field (also the above field), just put this in your password input:

```
<input type="password" name='any-filed-name-here-password' autoComplete='new-password' />
```

The important thing is to have the `autoComplete='new-password'`

Answer (score 3):

Id like to thank and expand on @Elie Bsaisbes answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000217/16538978

For the life of me, autoComplete = "off" / new-password etc... would only work on some forms, and not others. Only in chrome. Finally, the solution was to add a custom name as said in the linked answer like so

```
             <TextField      
                name="noAutoFill"
                label="Password"
                variant="standard"
                defaultValue=""
                id="password"
                type="password"
              />
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this recently. I tried everything I found on the web but ultimately the fix that worked for me was to do the following.

1. DO NOT set the type="password" on the TextField component
2. DO Set it along with auto**C**omplete: 'new-password' on the input props like this:

   ```
   <TextField
      label="Password"
      className={classes.textField}
      name="password"
      inputProps={{
         type:"password",
         autoComplete: 'new-password'
      }} />
   ```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me, but I changed the input type to search and it worked:

```
<TextField type="search" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

You do no longer need to provide the autoComplete='off' for the AutoComplete component on the master branch. It's added by default.

Check [this thread](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/2653) for more details.

Comment: it is related to AutoComplete component not for TexField When I pass autocomplete to texfield the react render it to input, but it does not work.

Comment: It applies to Texfield as well. You don’t need to pass autoComplete=“off” it is default now. <TextField
  autoComplete='off'
  floatingLabelText="From"
 ...
/>

Comment: I added the screenshot for that, looks like TexField has not autocompleted by default. But the problem with type='password', when I create a new user and save his password, and after that create the new one, the browser propose has already saved the previous password in the browser. I need to avoid it as admin

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute to the

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{
    autoComplete: "none",
  }}
  error={!!errors.fieldname}
  {...field}
  label="Field Name"
  required
/>;
```

Comment: Does not appear to work. Only works if the `id` of the field is removed

Answer (score 0):

If the autoComplete doesn't work, keep it but add a unique 'name' property to the component

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [readOnly, setReadOnly] = useState(true)

// render 
<TextField
  label="Password"
  name="password"
  readOnly={readOnly}
  onFocus={e => setReadOnly(false)}
  sx={{
    '& input': {
        textSecurity: 'disc',
        '-moz-text-security': 'disc',
        '-webkit-text-security': 'disc',
    },
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below fix worked for me

```
          <TextField
              inputProps={{
                autocomplete: 'off',
                form: {
                  autocomplete: 'off',
                },
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was auto-completing due to `type="text"`

```
         <TextField
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            onChange={handleSearch}
            size="small"
            placeholder="Search Customer"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <Iconify
                    icon="eva:search-fill"
                    sx={{
                      color: 'text.disabled',
                    }}
                  />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
```

After I removed `type="text"` and added `type="search"` it stopped auto-completing

```
         <TextField
            type="search"
            fullWidth
            onChange={handleSearch}
            size="small"
            placeholder="Search Customer"
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <Iconify
                    icon="eva:search-fill"
                    sx={{
                      color: 'text.disabled',
                    }}
                  />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
```