# Material UI <Autocomplete/> remove browser suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have problem with Material-ui Autocomplete:

```
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
```

I am using then in:

```
 <Autocomplete
        id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
        autoComplete={false}
        options={states}
        disableCloseOnSelect
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        onChange={onStateChange}
        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Checkbox
              icon={icon}
              checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
              checked={selected}
            />

            {option.name}
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="State"
            placeholder="Enter state"
          />
        )}
      />
```

Nothing important in this code but I face this issue:

[image]

I am getting the browser suggestion. How I can remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304062/material-ui-textfield-disable-browser-autocomplete), you should add `autoComplete="off"` to your TextField.

Comment: <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="State"
            placeholder="Enter state"
            autoComplete="off"
          /> 
but same result

Comment: There are additional workarounds proposed in the linked answer. Have you tried these?

Comment: And I see in the html spec that you could try to wrap your component in a form with autocomplete=off https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-off

Comment: Wrapping the component in <form> actually solved the issue. Thanks!